# How to perform a polymorphism explicit query on a Criteria query?

Tags: java, hibernate, polymorphism, criteria

I want to perform a criteria count query on my supertype Class which has its own HBM and not count the subclasses.

The query would then be a "non-polymorphic" query.

I tried by adding polymorphism="explicit" to my hbm and it works, but i'd like to do it only on one query and not on every queries.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% what you are after, but you can specify the class type in a query like this:

```
select user from User as user where user.class=MyUserClass;
```

So in Hibernate, you can refer to "class" attribute to filter out results based on what class type the object has.

Comment: *Comment from [Alessandro Dionisi](http://stackoverflow.com/users/323044/alessandro-dionisi):* This approach doesn't work because of this exception: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer